# Want to show text message for specific shipping method on checkout in magento2

Tags: magento2.2.4

I have a custom shipping method. If I select that custom shipping method, I need to render the custom message below shipping method list. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Copy file from

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

and paste into your theme as shown in the following path

> app/design/frontend/namespace/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html

Now find following table tag

```
<table class="table-checkout-shipping-method">
    .
    .
    .
</table>
```

Add your message after this table as shown in following code

```
<table class="table-checkout-shipping-method">
    .
    .
    .
</table>
<div class="custom-shipping-method-message" style="display: none;">This is custom shipping method message</div>
```

Now Add following jQuery code your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"], function($) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('body').on('click', '.table-checkout-shipping-method input[type="radio"]', function(){
                var code = 'your_custom_shipping_method_code';
                // you can check your custom shipping method code using inspect element
                // you can see the code in the value of input type radio

                if(jQuery(this).val() == code){
                    jQuery('.custom-shipping-method-message').show();
                } else {
                    jQuery('.custom-shipping-method-message').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Run the following command

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: script is not run .
I have to console.log('msg'); also but no any message in console i am using 2.3.2v

Comment: Please add your script here so I can check

Comment: i resolve this by override shipping.js file in my custom module